# Unable to set Button width in Android

Tags: android, button, layout, user-interface

I am able to control the height but somehow it does not make any difference to the button width.

```
    // Table Row for Previous button
    TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(this);

    tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tableRow1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

    // Button - Previous
    Button btnPrev = new Button(this);
    btnPrev.setText("< Previous");
    btnPrev.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);

    tableRow1.addView(btnPrev);

    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btnPrev.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 20;
    params.width = 60;

    btnPrev.setLayoutParams(params);


    // TextView for Previous button
    TextView textView11 = new TextView(this);
    textView11.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    textView11.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textView11.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    textView11.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
    textView11.setText("New Entry Form");

    tableRow1.addView(textView11);

    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = textView11
            .getLayoutParams();
    params1.height = (int) dipHeight;
    textView11.setLayoutParams(params1);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow1);
```

I tried changing few things here and there but no look.

Can someone from you take a time and help me on this?

Comment: please provide the xml code

Comment: i changed width=300 and its working fine.whats your problem ?

Comment: @Govind: A lot of answers have been given below. Look at them and accept/upvote the  answers that help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace this code
tableRow1.addView(btnPrev);

android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btnPrev.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 20;
params.width = 60;
btnPrev.setLayoutParams(params);

             to
tableRow1.addView(btnPrev,new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(20,60));
```

Comment: Well I did as you suggest, the button does not appear now.

Answer (score 0):

to set button width & height use below code

```
btnPrev.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btnPrev.setwidth(60);
btnPrev.setheight(20);
```

Comment: This gives runtime error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

You can set button width in two ways:

**Via java :**

```
 Button.setWidth(int width);
```

**Via XML properties :**

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/ButtonPrev" 
 android:layout_below="@id/output" 
 android:text="7" 
 android:minWidth="100dp">
</Button>
```

The property : `android:minWidth` will set the width of the button.

**Reference :**  [Set width of Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796219/set-width-of-button-in-android)

Comment: I am doing it programatically so cannot use XML.

Answer (score 0):

`View.requestLayout()` maybe what you want?

Comment: Did not get you dear, can you please elaborate.

Comment: after setup view's layout params, call request layout to make them work.